# How do I keep a textarea scrolled to the top in Firefox 4, like in previous Firefox versions?

Tags: firefox, textarea, firefox4

Firefox 4 automatically scrolls a textarea to its bottom if the content exceeds the viewable size.  Previous versions of Firefox didn't do that.

Is there something, perhaps an about:config option, that I can tweak to make it behave like it used to?

Comment: That's not default behavior.  Do you have an extension that causes this to happen?

Comment: You're right.  Looking that the site, they use JavaScript to focus on the text_area in question.  Without the call to focus, the text_area remains scrolled to the top, but with the focus call, it gets scrolled to the bottom.  Firefox 4 is the only browser I've seen that exhibits this behavior.  (Also, I disabled all extensions to ensure that wasn't the issue)

Comment: Ah, yes.  With the `focus()` call you would get that behavior.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353539 for the reason Firefox 4 does that.  It looks like webkit puts the caret at the beginning of the text on focus, not at the end.  Opera has the same (buggy) behavior Firefox used to have: the caret goes at the end, but is not scrolled into view.

Answer (score 0):

> Ah, yes. With the focus() call you would get that behavior. See http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353539 for the reason Firefox 4 does that. It looks like webkit puts the caret at the beginning of the text on focus, not at the end. Opera has the same (buggy) behavior Firefox used to have: the caret goes at the end, but is not scrolled into view